# What is the best pattern for lazy creating a Rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-loading

I have a model, let's say `Cat`, and I want to create a new model, `Owner`. A `Cat` `has_one :owner`, but when I created the `Cat` model, the `Owner` model didn't yet exist.

Without resorting to backfilling the new `Owner` model for each `Cat`, I want to have an easy way so if I call `@cat.owner.something`, and `@cat.owner` doesn't exist yet, it will call `@cat.create_owner` on the fly and return it.

I've seen this done a few different ways, but I am wondering what is the most Rails-esque way of tackling this, since I need to do this quite often.

Comment: Gitlab uses: `has_one :owner` and `def owner; super.presence || build_owner; end`
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen this done before but decided to give it a shot anyways.

I first aliased the association method `owner` in the `Cat` model to keep a backup of the original method. I overrode the `owner` method to call the `build_owner` method (returns a new `Owner` object through the association) if the original method returns nil. Otherwise, return the `original_owner_method` object.

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner

  alias :original_owner_method :owner

  def owner
    if original_owner_method.nil? 
      build_owner
    else
      original_owner_method
    end
  end
```

So now if you call:
`cat = Cat.first`

Assuming it doesn't have an owner, it will build a new Owner object when you call:
`cat.owner.name`

It will return nil, but still build the owner object on the `cat.owner` part of the chain without calling method_missing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having an owner created the first time it is accessed, I would use a callback to create the owner. This ensures that the owner is never nil, and will automatically rollback a Cat creation if the callback fails.

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_owner

private

  def create_owner
    return true unless owner.nil?

    create_owner(:default => 'stuff')
  end

end
```

Update: While I would still recommend the above approach for new applications, since you already have existing records you may want something more like this:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
  def owner
    super || create_owner(:default => 'stuff')
  end
end
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because I'm in a situation where there are many cat objects already created, and I don't want to have to be checking for the existence of the owner association whenever I reference it.

Comment: Got it. Added another option and made one minor change to original solution

Comment: Tried your second solution, and that didn't seem to work either. Got `no superclass method 'owner' for #<Cat:...>`

Answer (score 1):

In a general way for this sort of problem, I think this is the most "rubyish"

```
def owner
  @owner ||= create_owner
end
```

In rails, the way I would do something like this

```
def owner
  @owner ||= Owner.find_or_create(cat: self)
end
```

But in a general way I would try to figure out a way to use a Cat#create_owner or an Owner#create_cat and try to avoid the whole problem in the first place if i could.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding those default attribute getters/setters which come from `ActiveRecord::Base` is, in my experience, a dangerous practice - there be dragons. I'll explain by example which tripped me up.

I used the `super || create_association` pattern suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6741356/2517033). You can end up with a tricky bug like this one:

```
From: /Users/mec/Sites/zipmark/service/spec/models/vendor_application_spec.rb @ line 39 :

    34:         subject.read_attribute(:ledger_id).should be_blank
    35:       end
    36: 
    37:       it "lazily creates the association" do
    38:         subject.ledger
 => 39:         binding.pry
    40:         subject.reload.ledger_id.should be_present
    41:       end
    42:     end
    43:   end
    44: 

[1] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup>)> subject.ledger
#<Ledger:0x007fc3c30ad398> {
   :id => "cf0ac70e-ce23-4648-bf3f-85f56fdb123a",
   :created_at => Wed, 30 Sep 2015 17:56:18 UTC +00:00,
   :updated_at => Wed, 30 Sep 2015 17:56:18 UTC +00:00,
   :description => "Freshbooks Ledger"
}
[2] pry(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup>)> subject.reload.ledger_id
nil
```

I was mistakenly expecting Rails magic to update the record at hand (`self`) with its newly-created `ledger` record. I ended up re-writing my overloaded `#ledger` method to the following:

```
def ledger
  super || begin
    ledger = create_ledger(description: "#{name} Ledger")
    update_column(:ledger_id, ledger.id)
    ledger
  end
end
```